# Какое слово лучше употребить?

Tags: синонимы

Какое слово лучше употребить относительно листа бумаги, но маленьких размеров: листик, листочек, листок?

Comment: Лучше дать в контексте.

Answer (score 2):

**Согласно словарю, используются все три слова** (в значении лист бумаги и лист дерева): листик и листок ―  уменьшительное значение, листочек ―  уменьшительно-ласкательное значение.

**Примеры:**

Над протокой, раскинувший ветви, Тополь первый **листок** уронил. В левой руке он держал **листок**, мелко исписанный с обеих сторон.

Каждый **листочек** был густо исписан с двух сторон мельчайшим бисерным почерком Каждый **листочек** буквально купался в солнечных лучах.

Он протянул ему **листик** из записной книжки. Каждый **листик**, каждый луч божий любите. Всё время они или куда-то бегут, или откуда-то возвращаются и всегда с собой тащат или какой-нибудь **листик**, или комочек земли, или хвойную иголку.

**По частотности употребления** листок чаще относится к бумажному маленькому листу, а листик ―  к растениям.